# Would verifying the integrity of my website by comparing digest on the client side work?

Tags: hash, man-in-the-middle

So today I read about the [sub-resource integrity attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) feature for browsers. And I though of using the same concept to verify the integrity of my HTML to protect against tempering by my web host or other MITM attacks that SSL was not able to prevent.

Basically I'm thinking of running my HTML through a hash function on load and compare the output to the correct digest that is sent along with the HTML file. If they do not match then I'll show a warning and offer to leave the site.

This is under the assumption that my website was not specifically targeted.

Now users might ignore my message just like they ignore certificate warnings but that is on them.

Personally I think this makes sense, but is it flawed and provide a false sense of security? At least I don't think it makes matters worse.

Answer (score 1):

> ...to protect against tempering by my web host...

If you do not trust your hosting provider, all bets are off. They have full control over your website, and no clever tricks are going to change that.

> ...or other MITM attacks that SSL was not able to prevent.

TLS is not perfect, but it's good. You should focus your effort on using it properly (e.g. supported cipher suits, HSTS, etc.). Trying to build your own home brew fix for any weakneses in TLS is not a productive way to spend your time and energy.

> Basically I'm thinking of running my HTML through a hash function on load and compare the output to the correct digest that is sent along with the HTML file. If they do not match then I'll show a warning and offer to leave the site.

This offers no protection at all. If the attacker can modify the page, they can easily just disable this check or change the correct hash. Sure, that would require some special attention to your site in particular. But an attacker that can break TLS but not bypass this is not a realistic threat model. It's like assuming a bank robber will be able to cut through the steel door but not break a window.

> At least I don't think it makes matters worse.

In an of itself, it does not make things worse. But you have limited resources, and wasting them on things that are mostly pointless means you are not using them for things that would actually make you more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Using a hash to check HTML content will only work in a limited set of circumstances.

Any of the following will change the content read in the browser and therefore change the hash:

- interference by the web server (e.g. Apache/Nginx);
- web accelerator (e.g. Cloudflare); and
- browser (e.g. removal of meta http-equiv CSP nonce so that it can't be sniffed).